# Comparing two numbers in different columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
Perners Coursetype ID   Completed   Missing
10169299    71013531    X   
10169299    71004455    X   
10169299    71013525    X   
10169299    71013534    X   
10169299    71013529    X   
10169299    71013526    X   
10169299    71009239    X   
10169299    71014108    X   
10169299    71013533    X   
10169299    71004680    X   
10169299    71005007    X   
10169299    71013528        X
10169299    71014101    X   
10169299    71014102    X   
10169299    71014106    X   
10169299    71014105    X   
10169299    71014103    X   
10169299    71014107    X   
10169299    71013707    X   
10169299    71006168    X   
10169299    71005010    X   
10169299    71013527    X   
10169299    71014776    X
```

I'm trying to show that if some one took 71013528 or 71014776  then both classes were completed in an Access Database.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to represent it for example in a query output you can use `IIF` in combination with `Dlookup`.
maybe like this:
`IIF(Coursetype ID=71013528 or CourstypeID=71014776,IFF(Dlookup(Completed,TableName,CoursetypeID=71014776)=x OR Dlookup(Completed,TableName,CoursetypeID=71013528)=x,x,Completed),Completed)` (hope it's not to mixed up, but you'll get the idea).

However your data should be correct in the first place, you should handle that in the form where a user inserts the data.